# undefined symbol: GTIFGetGCSInfoEx

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geoserver, postgresql-11, centos8

In Progress 11 When I am trying to create a Postgis extension I encounter this error.
My environment is CentOS 8, with Postgress11-server, postgis25_11 and gdal-3.0.4-5.el8.x86_64

**ERROR:** could not load library "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/rtpostgis-2.5.so": /usr/gdal31/lib/libgdal.so.27: undefined symbol: **GTIFGetGCSInfoEx**

- Any idea what might cause this error?
- FYI, both of the library libgdal.so.27 and rtpostgis-2.5.so exist in the path above.

Answer (score 4):

By default Centos 8 will install libgeotiff15, which doesn't expose that symbol - You need to use [libgeotiff16](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory/geotiff/geotiff.changes?expand=0).

> - update to 1.6.0:
>
> - Add support for OGC GeoTIFF 1.1
> - Expose GTIFGetPCSInfoEx(), GTIFGetProjTRFInfoEx(), GTIFGetGCSInfoEx(), GTIFGetDatumInfoEx(), GTIFGetEllipsoidInfoEx(), GTIFGetPMInfoEx(), GTIFGetUOMLengthInfoEx() and GTIFGetUOMAngleInfoEx() so that users can specify their own PROJ context

Just spent a whole day on this same ordeal. Hope you manage!

Quick and dirty:

`sudo dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install -y postgresql11-server postgresql11-contrib postgresql11-devel libgeotiff16 postgis25_11`